# error while using smartStore in salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Tags: ios, swift, salesforce-ios-sdk

I'm creating an ipad application which is integrated with salesforcemobilesdk-ios . for offline capability I'm using smartStore framework. while I'm creating the soup i'm passing SFSoupIndex's array.

> (i.e indecesArray)

You can see the code below.

```
let soupIndexForAccount__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "account__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "account__c")
        let soupIndexForAddress_Line_2__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "Address_Line_2__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "Address_Line_2__c")
        let soupIndexForCity__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "City__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "City__c")
        let soupIndexForName = SFSoupIndex(path: "Name", indexType: "string", columnName: "Name")
        let soupIndexForPhone__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "Phone__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "Phone__c")
        let soupIndexForPostal_Code__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "Postal_Code__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "Postal_Code__c")
        let soupIndexForIsPersonAccount = SFSoupIndex(path: "IsPersonAccount", indexType: "string", columnName: "IsPersonAccount")
        let indecesArray:NSArray = NSArray(objects: soupIndexForAccount__c,soupIndexForAddress_Line_2__c,soupIndexForCity__c,soupIndexForName,soupIndexForPhone__c,soupIndexForPostal_Code__c,soupIndexForIsPersonAccount)
        let registeredOrNot = self.store.registerSoup("Address", withIndexSpecs: indecesArray as [AnyObject])
            print(registeredOrNot)
        exists = self.store.soupExists("Address")
        print(exists)
            let tempToCheck = self.store.allSoupNames()
        let toSee = self.store.indicesForSoup("Address")
```

`exists` has value `true`. That means we can understand that there is `Address` soup exists. When I'm trying to retrive `allSoupNames()` I found `nil` value in `tempToCheck` . `toSee` variable have to have the values of indexes that we insert if there was no mistake. But it is showing `nil`.

Please help me finding the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking like you have made a `store` declaration wrongly. Everything is perfect.

globally you need to declare a store variable

```
var store = SFSmartStore()
```

in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
store = SFSmartStore.sharedStoreWithName(kDefaultSmartStoreName) as! SFSmartStore
```

Hope it will work :)